# How to acquire get parameter in the post

Tags: django

how can i access to my 'back' get parameter? Django says that it isn't any GET data in request, but query string looks like `/?back=http://myapp/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=http://example.com/&response_type=code&client_id=222222.`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(request.GET.get('back','/'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to url encode the value of the `?back=...` GET parameter. So instead of:

```
/?back=http://myapp/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=http://example.com/&response_type=code&client_id=222222
```

you should have

```
/?back=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D222222
```

If you are generating the GET parameter within a Django template you can use the built-in [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode) template filter. So something like:

```
<a href="{{ url 'my_view' }}?back={{ redirect_url|urlencode }}"></a>
```

If you are using javascript to generate the parameter, you can use the built in [`encodeURI` method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)